# Use nwalign() with any type of sequence

Tags: matlab

I require an approximate string matching function for Matlab. I found out that the Bioinformatics toolbox has the [Needleman–Wunsch algorithm](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/bioinfo/ref/nwalign.html) by calling nwalign(). The only problem is that it only works with amino acid sequences. So when I try compare strings with numbers and other symbols, I get an error saying: "Both sequences must be amino acids."

Is there a way to allow the nwalign() function to accept any type sequence or is there another matlab function which can perform approximate string matching which is not limited to bioinformatics?

Answer (score 2):

This has been discussed in this [thread](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/281532)

It explains how to use a non-documented function to perform alignments with symbols other than aminoacids or nucleotides.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `python's nwalign()` .

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/nwalign

It seems to take strings as arguments (yet to look at the source), so if you have numpy sequences or lists, you may need to convert them.

Answer (score 0):

You can try in this way :

```
[Score,Align] =nwalign(Seq1,Seq2,'Alphabet','NT')
```

In this way you can align two nucleotidic sequences.

Which kind of scoring matrix are you going to use?